# theme-my-login не проводит авторизацию через виджет

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Собственно сабж. Авторизация со страницы - идёт нормально. А вот виджетом - ни в какую
Добавил в меню блок авторизации

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Войти</a>
            <div class="menu-auth-form">
                <ul>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'menu-auth-block' ); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Авторизация просто не идёт

- Theme my login:  6.4.16
- WP: 4.9.6

Может где-то нужно "пнуть" виджет, чтобы он заработал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не идёт"? И см логи. И кто тебя научил в ФОРМУ пихать сайдбар? Это трусы поверх шубы.

Comment: В логах ничего нет. Увы. Туда смотрел в первую голову.

Answer (score 0):

Просто вывести виждет этого плагина в сайбар темы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выкинуть этот корявый код.

> Theme my login: 6.4.16

[Актуальная версия](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) - 7,0,5

Comment: В смысле? Виджет и так в сайдбаре. Просто он скрыт пока на него курсор не наведён.

Comment: @VladKn ПРОСТО вывести (я добавил картинку)